# ASP.NET 5 - beta8: no rebuild in background

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

Before beta8 it was possible to start a Web Application, change some of the code (e. g. the ViewBag.Message of the About-View), save and refresh the browser - voilá, the new Message is displayed **without rebuilding the project**.

Now when creating a new Web Application with beta8 which uses DNX and Kestrel this seems no longer to work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

Beta8 contains a new library called 'dnx watch' which monitors your project files for changes during execution and automatically rebuilds the project.  Install it by running the following from a command prompt:

`dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher`

Additionally, make sure you've installed the beta8 [web tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442) for Visual Studio.

Finally, make sure you're not running in debug mode as code changes will not reload projects while running with the debugger attached. CTRL+F5 will start your web project without the debugger.

You can read up on this and the other changes in beta8 here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx